# Create corpus in R from multiple folders

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a Corpus from inside a folder A which contains many folder B,C,D,E....
each with one file inside.

I know you can create a Corpus using a folder that contain many files like this:

```
library(tm)
data = Corpus(DirSource("folder with many files"),
    readerControl = list(language = “en”))
```

but how to do this in a folder with many folders each containing one file.

Thanks!

I get a folder/file listing like this:

```
 [1] "10000/10000-0" "10005/10005-0" "100/100-0"     "10021/10021-0"
   [5] "10033/10033-0" "10037/10037-0" "1004/1004-0"   "10045/10045-0"
   [9] "10049/10049-0" "10055/10055-0" "10071/10071-0" "10079/10079-0"
  [13] "10095/10095-0" "10099/10099-0" "1010/1010-0"   "10101/10101-0"
  [17] "10103/10103-0" "10105/10105-0" "10123/10123-0" "10125/10125-0"
  [21] "10129/10129-0" "10146/10146-0" "10152/10152-0" "10156/10156-0"
  [25] "10166/10166-0" "10168/10168-0" "10176/10176-0" "10188/10188-0"
  [29] "10192/10192-0" "10206/10206-0" "10208/10208-0" "10216/10216-0"
  [33] "10220/10220-0" "10226/10226-0" "10236/10236-0" "10238/10238-0"
  [37] "10246/10246-0" "10258/10258-0" "10272/10272-0" "10274/10274-0"
  [41] "1028/1028-0"   "10284/10284-0" "10288/10288-0" "10292/10292-0"
  [45] "10294/10294-0" "10306/10306-0" "10308/10308-0" "10310/10310-0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `recursive=TRUE`

> DirSource(directory = ".", encoding = "unknown", pattern = NULL,
>             recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE)
>
> recursive  Logical. Should the listing recurse into directories?

So you example becomes:

```
Corpus(DirSource("folder with many files"),
    readerControl = list(language = “en”),rec=TRUE)
```

**EDIT**

I create a new directocry source based on `list.files`.

```
recursiveDirSource(directory_path){
    d <- list.files(directory_path,rec=TRUE,full.names=TRUE)

    isfile <- logical(length(d))
    for (i in seq_along(d)) isfile[i] <- !file.info(d[i])["isdir"]
    s <- tm:::.Source(readPlain, "unknown", sum(isfile), TRUE, basename(d), 
                                        0, TRUE, class = "DirSource")
    s$FileList <- d
    s
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in .Source(readPlain, encoding, sum(isfile), TRUE, basename(d[isfile]),  : 
  vectorized sources must have positive length

Comment: @bytebiscuit this works fine for me. The error comes from your files. I can't help you without data.

Comment: @bytebiscuit what do you have when you do this `dir(PATH_TO_YOUR_MAIN_DIR,rec=TRUE)`?

Comment: check the question , that's the result I'm getting by running dir(PATH_TO_YOUR_MAIN_DIR,rec=TRUE)

Comment: i tried it in another example... i created a folder with 3 folders inside with each having a file and some text but it returned the same error!

Comment: @bytebiscuit try my new function please

Comment: Hi thanks! Not sure if i should use s directly as the new DirSource ... or how do I proceed to create the Corpus from here!

Comment: something like `Corpus(recursiveDirSource(dir_path),...)`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I had to add the pattern and set `recursive` to `TRUE`

```
corpus <- Corpus(
  DirSource("/path/to/maim/folder/", encoding = "UTF-8",pattern="*.html",recursive=TRUE),
  readerControl = list(language = "en")
)
```